# Understanding partial differential notation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Say i have $$z = x^2 + y$$ $$y = 2x$$
What sense does $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ make? Can we talk about changing $z$ as $x$ changes but keeping $y$ constant?

Answer (score 0):

Since $z=z(x,y) = z(x,2x)$ I would define a function $w(x) = z(x,y(x))$. By the chain rule
$$\frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x+2.$$
The expression for $\frac{dw}{dx}$ is called *total derivative* of $z$ with respect to $x$, and it is denoted by $\frac{dz}{dx}$. Be careful: in this case $z$ is a function of two variables, but the notation reminds the ordinary derivative for functions of one variable. Notice that $\partial z/\partial x$ is just a bit of the total derivative.

Comment: No, $\partial z/\partial x\ne dz/dx$.

Comment: I edited the answer explaining a bit better what I meant.

Comment: I don't believe that this answer enlightens the meaning of the partial derivatives.

Comment: In fact the point here is that one should use the total derivative to understand the various notations. That is why I concentrate more on the definition of total derivative and show where the partial derivative of $z$ crops up in its expression.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$ indeed denotes the variation of $z$ under a variation of $x$, *while other variables are held constant*.

Undisputably,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2x\text{ and }\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1.$$

If $y$ varies at the same time as $x$, you should consider a total variation

$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$

and 
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+1\cdot2.$$

Comment: It seems to me that we are looking at a constrained partial derivative.

Comment: @CarlMummert: this is an ordinary derivative, computed via partial derivatives and the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that’s correct.
$$z = x^2+y$$
For the partial derivative $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, we look at the change in $z$ while $x$ changes, while treating all other variables (in this case, $y$) as constants.
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^2 + 0$$
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x}$$
Had the question been for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, we would’ve treated $x$ like a constant.
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y$$
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 1}$$

Comment: It seems to me we are looking at constrained partial derivatives in this problem. Given $y = 2x$, it is impossible to change $x$ without changing $y$. It would be possible to expand your answer to address this issue.

Comment: @CarlMummert: so you mean that it is impossible to write $\partial(x^2+2y)/\partial x=2x$ ? This would be as weird as saying "I can't compute $y'(2)$ because $2$ is a constant and there is no $dx$."

Comment: @Yves Daoust: it is possible to "write" that, of course - it is the formal partial derivative - but it does not correspond geometrically to the derivative along a path contained in the constraint curve $y = 2x$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: $\partial z/\partial x=2x$, full stop.

Comment: @Yves Daoust:  well, the *formal* partial derivative is $2x$, but not the geometrical one. Geometrically, a partial derivative is a derivative along a path in the domain in which $x$ is changing and as many of the remaining variables as possible are fixed.   I'm not sure what else to say - this is a relatively standard topic, as in https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/MA103-Auroux-2.2.41.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are looking at the function
$$
f(x,y) = x^2 + y
$$
restricted to the line $y = 2x$. This is an example of a *constrained partial derivative*. Here is a [video from MIT Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/video-lectures/lecture-14-non-independent-variables/) about these.

These come up in various settings, particularly in applications of calculus to physics where a function may depend on several variables that are themselves linked by physical laws.  These laws may prevent us from keeping all but one variable in an expression constant. For example, if we have the constraint $PV = kT$ where $k$ is constant, and we look at $f(P,V,T)$, we cannot keep $V$ and $T$ constant while changing $P$ without violating the constraint. We have to let one of $V$ or $T$ vary, while fixing the other one.

In cases like this, we need to distinguish between the *formal* partial derivatives that ignore the constraint and the *actual* (geometrical) partial derivatives that we would actually measure using paths that stay in the constraint.

By definition, formal partial derivatives ignore the constraints, giving
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1
$$

These can be somewhat misleading, however, because given the constraint $y = 2x$ it is impossible to fix $y$ and change $x$.  The actual (geometrical) partial derivative will be measurable as the derivative along a particular curve contained in the constraint, so that $x$ changes with rate $1$ as we move along the curve.

With the constraint $y = 2x$, we are really in a one-dimensional setting.  We can choose which of $x$ or $y$ will be our one independent variable. If we choose $x$, then we have $f(x) = x^2 + 2x$, and $\partial f/\partial x = 2x + 2$ is just the regular derivative.

A less degenerate example is $h(x,y,z) = 2x + 3y + z$ on the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Now, to find $\partial h /\partial x$, we can again choose *one* of $y$ and $z$ to fix, because the surface is two-dimensional rather than three-dimensional. We cannot fix both $y$ and $z$ and change $x$, because $\{x,y,z\}$ is not an independent set of coordinates on the constraint surface. But we can choose which of the two ($y$ or $z$) will be fixed. Once we do that, we can compute the constrained partial derivative using the chain rule:
$$
0 = 2x\,dx + 2y\,dy + 2z\,dz\\
-2x = 2y(\partial y/ \partial x) + 2z (\partial z/\partial x)
$$

In this case, there will be *two* different $\partial/\partial x$ derivatives, corresponding to the two choices of an independent coordinate system.

- If we let $\partial y/\partial x = 0$ then $\partial z /\partial x = -x/z$. This corresponds to following a path on the sphere parallel to the $xz$ plane.   This is sometimes written $\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y = -\frac{x}{z}$ where the $\left (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y$ indicates that $\{x,y\}$ is our set of independent coordinates.
- If we let $\partial z/\partial x = 0$ then $\partial y/\partial x = -x/y$. This corresponds to following a path on the sphere parallel to the $xy$ plane.

The video I linked will have more examples of this.